# "We have but a choice to be responsible citizens"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

I am trying to phrase this: "We don't have any other choice but to be responsible citizens" as "We have but a choice to be responsible citizens". Is this correct? Or have I said exactly the opposite?

It would be great if someone could explain "have but a" phrase more elaborately.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Akhila. Have you found a suitable example using 'but' in a dictionary? For instance, in CED, AHD, Lexico? Tell the community which ones you've looked in without success, otherwise, to help avoid needless duplication of effort. // I've found "He's but a wee bairn" (or similar) very quickly. 'But' = 'nobbut' = 'merely, just'. But I wouldn't speak that way myself in 99+% of contexts.

Comment: I think the phrase you want is "We have no choice but...".

Answer (score 2):

"Have but ___" is a way of saying you have a said amount/number/degree of something. It is a phrase that in standard use implies scarcity.

- I have but one chance left = I have exactly one chance left
- I have but seconds left to live = I have seconds left to live

Although the second one doesn't give you a definite number of seconds, the phrase implies that how many ever are left are clearly not adequate.

So your sentence does mean what you intended it to, but your instinct is right in that it sounds just a bit clunky and obtuse.

Answer (score -1):

You have two different senses of *but* here . . .

***But* the preposition meaning *except***:

> *We don't have any other choice **but** to be responsible citizens.*
>
> *We don't have any other choice **except** to be responsible citizens.*

***But* the adverb meaning *only***:

> *We have **but** a choice to be responsible citizens.*
>
> *We have **only** a choice to be responsible citizens.*

I think you can see that your adverb *but* doesn't really work there. Try, perhaps:

> *We have **but** one choice: to be responsible citizens.*
>
> *We have **only** one choice: to be responsible citizens.*

<sub>[See: *but* at Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/but)</sub>

Comment: Why does it not work in your opinion? I agree that its clunky. Both the alternatives you've given are arguably better, but the sentence she used does convey the intended meaning, does it not?